# How to flip rows and columns on survey data in Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have survey data in a pandas dataframe where each row is a complete survey response.  It currently looks like this:

| name | Question 1 | Question 2 | Question 3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| John | agree | disagree | neither |
| Sally | disagree | neither | agree |

I want to flip it so the questions are in each row, and the results are tabulated across the rows, like this:

| Question | disagree | neither | agree |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Question 1 | 1 | 0 | 1 |
| Question 2 | 1 | 1 | 0 |
| Question 3 | 0 | 1 | 1 |

The responses follow a strict 5-point likert scale, so they are all consistent.

I tried to loop through a list of columns with questions and summarize using value_counts(), but I was unable to transpose it into a new df.

Answer (score 2):

Try `pd.crosstab`:

```py
df = df[["Question 1", "Question 2", "Question 3"]].stack().droplevel(level=0)
print(pd.crosstab(df.index, df).rename_axis(index="Question", columns="").reset_index())
```

Prints:

```
     Question  agree  disagree  neither
0  Question 1      1         1        0
1  Question 2      0         1        1
2  Question 3      1         0        1
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`melt`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.melt.html) and [`pivot_table`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot_table.html):

```
out = (df.filter(like='Question').melt(var_name='Question', value_name='Answer')
         .assign(Value=1).pivot_table(index='Question', columns='Answer',
                                      values='Value', aggfunc=max, fill_value=0))
print(out)

# Output
Answer      agree  disagree  neither
Question                            
Question 1      1         1        0
Question 2      0         1        1
Question 3      1         0        1
```

Another alternative with index manipulation:

```
out = (df.filter(like='Question').melt(var_name='Question', value_name='Answer')
         .assign(Value=1).set_index(['Question', 'Answer'])['Value']
         .unstack('Answer').fillna(0).astype(int))
```